# App_Code folder - are you missing a using directive or assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a cs file called MyCustomColumnClass.cs on App_Code folder.
It has a public class called MyCustomFilteringColumn : GridBoundColumn
The namespace is MyStuff.

on an aspx page

```
if (column is MyStuff.MyCustomFilteringColumn)
{
  (column as MyStuff.MyCustomFilteringColumn).ListDataSource =
     GetFilterTable(column.DataField);
}
```

Error:
MyStuff could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also make sure the the file `MyCustomColumnClass.cs` has the `Build action: compile` property set on. If I'm not mistaken files thrown into App_Code folder get this by default but check it anyway.

Comment: I tried the Build action: Compile and able to have the intellisense work when I type using MyStuff. However after this I am getting an error CS0433: The type 'MyStuff.MyCustomFilteringColumn' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5a8ba6f0\42336f70\assembly\dl3\00dddbaf\dbddecd7_1854cb01\TelerikSample.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5a8ba6f0\42336f70\App_Code._azr1zza.dll'

Comment: Try cleaning/rebuilding the project.

Comment: I created the empty website and re-added all my files. The Build action: compile property was not set earlier but on the new empty website it was created automatically. I am marking yours as an answer as it solved the build error I had earlier encountered.

Comment: Setting the "Build Action" to "Compile" in the class' properties window worked for me in VS2010 using C# 4.  The class is now found in my code (in the Global.asax.cs) and intellisense now works in the IDE.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `using MyStuff;` on your aspx codebehind page.